# How to implement two level sidebar navigation with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'd like to implement a two level navigation inside a sidebar using JQuery Mobile.

By means of explaining what I am trying to achieve, consider I have 3 categories links, and (for example) 3 links in each category

Category 1
  - Link 1
  - Link 2
  - Link 3

Category 2
  - Link 1
  - Link 2
  - Link 3

Category 3
  - Link 1
  - Link 2
  - Link 3

And would like someway to avoid having the user have to browse down two links to try to get to any one page.

I've tried a few avenues using the  route;

1. Using data-role="collapsible", in an attempt to create headers for each category in the sidebar, any of which users could expand to click on the second level link
2. Using a series of select drop downs (for each category), and javascript to fire a page change on selecting any of the choices

The problem is that while both methods work nicely when used in a 'main content' page, as soon as I put them in a content-secondary container, neither of them work (the collapsible content is always expanded, and the javascript does not seem to fire)

Can anyone suggest either (a) a solution to the above problems I am having, or (b) an alternative way to skin this cat?

Edit:
You can see my earlier post trying to sort out the collpasible problem inside the secondary block at;
[Is it possible to have collapsible content inside a secondary div class with JQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067501/is-it-possible-to-have-collapsible-content-inside-a-secondary-div-class-with-jqu)

And a JSFiddle with sample code at http://jsfiddle.net/vinomarky/xfcdF/ , although Fiddle doesnt seem to work with secondary divs, so it will not render the sidebar correctly even if you expand the window

Comment: Can you show some code as well? A `<div data-role="collapsible">` for each category inside one common `<div data-role="collapsible-set">` should be a good solution, but make sure `data-collapsed="false"` is only set on the category you want to be expanded.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the original post to add links to some screen grabs to illustrate the issue as well as sample Fiddle code. I agree with you that a collapsible div inside a secondary page should be a good solution, but it doesnt work..... dont know why, just doesnt. I can Copy/paste the same code into a main block and it works fine, but not inside the secondary - the first link I added above shows screen grabs of what happens as you expand the screen width and the secondary div moves from the bottom of the page to a sidebar - note the collapse capability disapears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my suggestion on your previous thread. To do what you seem to want to do;

1. Include the style sheet you are using to define secondary content
   in JS fiddle to fiddle
2. Remove the parts that reveal collapsed content
3. Remove the parts that hide collapsible-headers

via:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AssidiousBlue/j8TM6/2/)
(please forgic some of the changes in the CSS - it's from my own project

Comment: Awesome.... dont pretend to understand it all yet - I'll have to sit down and digest it properly, but your Fiddle does exactly what I need so the answer is yours! Thx very much